# Moving GameObject based on Joystick input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, translate, joystick

I want to move the gameobject based on Joystick's input while the mobile is fixed in landscape mode.

Following is my code,

```
  selectedGameObject.transform.forward = new Vector3(joyStick.Horizontal, 0f, joyStick.Vertical);

  if(joyStick.Direction.y > 0)
  {
      selectedGameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(joyStick.Horizontal * 0.01f, 0.0f, joyStick.Vertical * 0.01f));
  }
  if (joyStick.Direction.y < 0)
  {
     selectedGameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(joyStick.Horizontal * 0.01f, 0.0f, -joyStick.Vertical * 0.01f));
  }
```

Unfortunately the gameobject moves oddly and sometimes in an opposite way. What am I missing?

Comment: First, you don't need those if statements, since both are doing the same thing. you just need to check if your y direction is not null and then do selectedGameObject.transform.Translate(new Vector3(joyStick.Horizontal * 0.01f, 0.0f, joyStick.Vertical * 0.01f)). second, instead of setting your forward vector, just rotate it to your horizontal value. this way, you don't need sideways motion, just translate it forward, and rotate the gameobject.

Comment: i tried removing the if loop. it just moves the opposite direction

Comment: then invert the value.. or rotate the inner gameObject to face the correct way

Comment: I have to invert it based on y value in order to prevent it from moving opposite but still it is not proper. it just moves oddly

Comment: what do you mean oddly? your y value spans from -1 to 1, meaning that if you translate your gameobject, it will go one way or the other based on that value. You don't actually even need to check if it is 0, because it has a dead zone, and the vector value will be 0 anyway.